# Layout dinâmico com invisibilidade, não consigo repor posição de elemento

Tags: android

A minha questão é secalhar simples eu é que ainda não percebo muito disto.

Tou a ter um problema com invisibilidade, eu tenho um LinearLayout vertical com dois botões e quando clico no primeiro aparece outro LinearLayout que eu defini e o segundo botão desce (tudo certo até aqui), porém quando clico no primeiro botão de novo para as textviews desaparecerem o segundo botão não volta à posição inicial, o que tenho de utilizar para isso ser possível?

XML

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/lol"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="LOLOLOLLOLOL"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="LOLOLOLLOLOL"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LOLatuabelha"
        android:id="@+id/belha"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

JAVA

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button botao;
        botao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        final LinearLayout lol = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lol);

        botao.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (lol.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                            lol.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                        else{
                            lol.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acontece que você está utilizando `View.INVISIBLE`, que vai apenas deixar seu `LinearLayout` invisível de fato, sem "retirá-lo" do seu layout, ocupando o mesmo espaço.

Para funcionar da forma que você deseja, basta alterar esta propriedade para `View.GONE`, como você mesmo utilizou no seu *XML*:

```
if (lol.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    lol.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
    lol.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: É isso mesmo, muito obrigado pela ajuda!